# How to clear the cache from entitymanager in Breeze

Tags: breeze

How to clear the cache from entityManager in Breeze,

Actually I am trying to remove  the criteria and saving the criteria, after saving the criteria if i get any error from server i am trying to remove the criteria.

```
  function (error) {
            var changedEntities = manager.getChanges([requestType, requestItemType, requestCriteriaItemType]);
            //rollback those entities
            for (var w = 0; w < changedEntities.length; w++) {
                changedEntities[w].entityAspect.rejectChanges();
            }

            ds.serviceName = originalServiceName;

            $rootScope.$broadcast("requestSaveComplete", {
                Successful: false,
                SaveResults: [],
                Errors: error.entityErrors
            });
```

I wrote the code like that, if I get any error I am removing the criteria and saving remaing criteria here I am getting problem , in entityManger it is not clearing the Cache

Comment: not sure I understand. What does this have to do with clearing the entityManager cache?

Comment: it storing the values but it is not clearing with that i am getting null values

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand the issue, but...

You can always clear the entityManager's cache by simply calling EntityManager.clear ( see http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_clear )

```
myEntityManager.clear();
```

Or you can remove individual entities from the cache by calling either EntityAspect.setDetached: ( http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityAspect.html#method_setDetached )

```
myEntity.entityAspect.setDetached();
```

or EntityManager.detachEntity (http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_detachEntity )

```
myEntityManager.detachEntity(myEntity);
```